# ImageMagick command to enlarge original image

Tags: imagemagick

I have a `canvas.png` image which is `2048 x 2048 px`.
I have a `background.jpg` image which is `1920 x 1080 px`.

I want to increase the size of the `background.jpg` and place it on `canvas.png`, it must fill the whole area but `background.jpg` should remain in proportion.

When the two images are composed I want to retain the original canvas size of `2048 x 2048 px`

[image: canvas.png]

[image: background.jpg]

Comment: To force resizing of the background, you can use ``convert background.jpg    -resize 2048x2048\!  background.jpg``

Comment: Yes, but then this loose the proportions. Would there be away to increase it's size without loosing its proportion? I could then crop it?

Comment: You have to choose a compromise (1) modifying aspect ratio (2) crop a part of it (3) do not fill all the canvas. Which one do you prefer (may be something else?)

Comment: I don't want to modify the aspect ratio. So how do I enlarge it so it's big enough and then crop to the canvas size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not want  to modify the aspect ratio, you can try:

```
convert background.jpg  -resize 2048x2048^ -gravity center -extent 2048x2048  fill_background.jpg
```

It gives:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what you want but I am using version 7 and it did not wwork properly with the convert in version 7:

```
magick KhzcT.png zjBGB.jpg -resize x2048 -gravity center -composite output.png
```

**For version 6 change magick to convert**

Somehow missed the answer from @xizwi